# Seeking QGIS solution to make aerial imagery ArcSDE compatible?

Tags: qgis, raster, enterprise-geodatabase, aerial-photography

Would like to avoid having to use 3d Analyst and use free raster tools in QGIS or elsewhere to make aerial rasters ArcSDE compatible. This [18 page work flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMWcE.jpg) is what I am trying to use.